# How to fix code igniter version difference error?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two projects with different version of Code Igniter. The first project is on CI 2.0.2 and the other one is on CI 3.0. When I implement the 3.0 project to my machine, the project name is missing in the address bar.

**Example:**

when I open the project for the first time, the address is `'http://localhost:8080/bsm/'`. But when I click login button to open Login form the address become `'http://localhost:8080/login'`. It should be `'http://localhost:8080/bsm/login/'`.

I have no issue with the 2.0.2 project. So, how to make the 3.0 project address bar displayed correctly?

**Update:**

- My base_url is`$config['base_url']= "http://localhost:8080/bsm/";`
- I notice my anchor is `<a href='/login'>Login</a>`. When I change it to `href='bsm/login'`, the address become `'http://localhost:8080/bsm/bsm/login/'`.
- My .htaccess

> ```
>   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>   RewriteEngine On
>   # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
>   #  slashes.
>   # If your page resides at
>   #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
>   # then use
>   # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
>   RewriteBase /
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bsm/index.php?/$1 [L]
> </IfModule>
>
> <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
>   # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
>   # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
>   # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin
>
>   ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
> </IfModule>
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust `base_url` in:

```
Application > Config > config.php
```

Also check `.htaccess` and make sure a subfolder is added to path:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bsm/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Or use:

```
RewriteBase /bsm
```

Since you edited explaining about links, either do this:

```
<a href='/bsm/login'>Login</a>
```

Or this

```
<a href='<?php print base_url(); ?>login'>Login</a>
```

Comment: It's working. But, that means I have to change all the navigation rule which are hundreds I wonder if there are another alternatives

Comment: You didn't use base_url() in other places?

Comment: You really should, either the way I showed it or via site_url(). In this case, you could open the entire project, in Sublime for example, and do a mass find & replace for href=" into href="<?php print base_url(); ?>